# migrating elixir 1.0 app to 1.2 and having issues with derive Collectable for module struct

Tags: upgrade, elixir, deprecation-warning

The 1.0 implementation looks like this.

```
defmodule Chat do
  use GenServer

  @derive [Access, Collectable]
  defstruct [api: APIClient, chat_id: nil, clients: %{}]

  def start_link(params), do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, params)

  def init(params) do
    state = Enum.into(params, %__MODULE__{})
    {:ok, state}
  end

  ...
end
```

First problem is that Access has been deprecated, does that mean I have to change the dot notation when accessing state fields?

Second problem is that if I don't remove the @derive Collectable I get this error `Collectable.Any is not available, cannot derive Collectable ...`.
Here `params` is a keyword list, I supose I could convert the keyword list to a `Map` with `state = Map.merge(%__MODULE__{}, Enum.into(params, %{}))` but feels terribly clumsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the particular `Collectable` issue, but there's a much better solution to your particular problem - constructing a struct from a list of key-value pairs.
You can use `Kernel.struct/2` for that. It won't only construct the struct for you, but also validate the keys, and use only those that really are in the struct. Since 1.2 there's `Kernel.struct!/2` that will raise in case any of the provided keys is invalid.

Comment: Thanks, I did `state = struct(__MODULE__, params)`